# Select file in Athena

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-athena

I am using AWS Athena . There are 2 files in the folder location specified while creating table . How to select a particular file while executing query ?

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things in no particular order:

It is best not to think about "folders" in S3 as folders.  I know the button says "Create Folder" in the web GUI.  Unfortunately, various desktop clients have continued the trend (thanks S3 Browser).  The way to think about folders in an S3 bucket is that they are part of the object key (sometimes I think of them as a "tag"). If you start working with the API, that will help minimize confusion!

Thus, Athena is going to have trouble differentiating between files with similar keys and you cannot specify just one file.  In the examples below, suppose I load car-makers.csv and car-names.csv into a bucket called "SOMEBUCKET" with the tag "SOMETAG."

If I run the following DDL:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS carnames_and_makers (
  id int,
  make string,
  model string
)
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED
 FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
 LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
LOCATION 's3://SOMEBUCKET/SOMETAG/';
```

I will end up with both carnames and car makers in the carnames_and_makers
table.

Unfortunately, you can't specify an object.

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS carnames_just_names (
  id int,
  make string,
  model string
)
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED
 FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
 LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
LOCATION 's3://SOMEBUCKET/SOMETAG/car-names.csv';
```

Results in an error like:

```
FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask. MetaException(message:Got exception: java.io.IOException Can't make directory for path 's3://SOMEBUCKET/SOMETAG/car-names.csv' since it is a file.)
```

I hope this explanation helps!

Using the cars dataset available at:
http://users.csc.calpoly.edu/~dekhtyar/365-Winter2015/index.html

Answer (score -2):

The location of files is specified by the `LOCATION` parameter of the `CREATE TABLE` statement.

You can specify a path, and all files within that path will be included as part of the table.

If you only wish to include one file, you could probably specify the full Key for the file (full path and filename) and it will probably just query that path. This will, of course, require specification in `CREATE TABLE`. You cannot change the path within the `SELECT` statement.

Comment: This doesn't work - you can specify a folder, but not a file.